# How do I display multiple markers by using Google iOS SDK from Network Request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I am new to the iOS programming. I have been working on project that needs to fetch and show multiple markers on map through the coordinates(Google iOS SDK). I Followed this [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3otcf28z267yzkl/Exploring-Google-Maps-For-iOS-FULL.pdf?dl=0) to create markers in the map.

I can get the response using NSLOG. What I want is to print those coordinates in the maps. Please give me a clear example in Objective-c.

Comment: can you show us response so we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on question here you can use multiple marker with the help of for loop like below.

```
NSArray *arrLatLong; // Get it from your response

for(NSDictionary *dictLocation in arrLatLong){

    GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(dictLocation[@"latitude"].doubleValue,dictLocation[@"longitude"].doubleValue);
    marker1.title = @"Lake Eola";
    marker1.snippet = @"Come see the swans";
    marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker1.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    //Assign that marker to your current MapView
    marker1.map = self.mapView;

}
```

Use this after getting response from server.

Hope this will help you.